# rewrite query string

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

i have a url `"www.abc.com/index.php?page/Secure"`

and i want to access it with `"www.abc.com/secure"`

im trying to add .htaccess loging for `"index.php?page/Secure"` 
but I was told i need to use `LocationMatch` and to do that i need to rewrite the url.

@mike, thanks your solution worked

But now im getting a 500 error when i try to secure the location with htaccess

```
<Location /secure>
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Secure Area"
     AuthUserFile .htpasswd
     Require valid-user
</Location>
```

`
my .htaccess and .htpasswd are on the same dir, which is the public/w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that specific page:

```
# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine on

#Create friendly URL
RewriteRule ^secure$ index.php?page/secure [L]
```

Try using: http://turnkey-buddy.com/mod_rewrite_tool/

It's a free rewrite generator. Works like a charm.

Comment: i only want that specific url to be re written